# How to achieve this scatter effect using Illustrator or photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, gradient, effects, brush

I have tried using scatter brushes in Illustrator but it is not exactly the same thing. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Hello Weiyi Wang, could you please show us a screenshot of your attempt? That way, we can more easily help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in Photoshop with custom brush you need to define (rectangle shape) and then play with the settings (remember that "roundness" in this case will be thickness of the shape. This is what you could get.

[image: Brush scattering]

In illustrator the easiest way (for me) would be do create few different patterns, fill objects with them, then expand and multiply and move them. The effect would look like this 
[image: ilustrator]

Create the object you will later use as a pattern. Select them and then move to swatches
[image: scatter1]
Then, make object you would like to fill and from "fill" list choose your pattern. 
[image: scatter3]

When object if filled choose Object --> Expand tick "fill" and will be able to move and overlap objects. Do is as many times as you want until you will be happy with results. 
[image: scatter2]

Using Direct Select Tool you can move single rectangles co you can add more random effect. 
The main advantage of illustrator is that you can add single rectangles to make the scatter look more random.

Comment: Is it possible to have a more detailed steps for the Illustrator effect? Thanks so much!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/EWw5D5C.png When I try to put multiple pattern over one another, for some reason it doesn't "go through" one another? In the picture shown they are actually three different pattern-filled objects, but it only show the first...please help :(

Comment: I added more step for illustrator. The "Expand" step is very important, if you don't do it pattern will behave as seamless for every object.